# How to display images of a particular Blog post?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

models.py

```py
class PostModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.TextField(null=True)
    body = models.TextField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

class ImagesPostModel(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(PostModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.I
```

views.py

```py
def show_posts(request):
    posts = PostModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    images = []
    for post in posts:
        images.append(ImagesPostModel.objects.filter(post=post))

    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'images': images,
    }

    return render(request, 'show_posts.html', context)
```

show_posts.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for post in posts %}

    {{post.title}}
    <br>
    {{post.body}}
    <br>
    {{post.data_time}}
    <br>
    {% for imgs in images %}
        {% for image in imgs %}
            {{image.post_id}}
            <img src="{{image.images.url}}" alt="postimage" style="width: 300px;">
        <br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

        <hr>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

I want the images of a post to be displayed which are related to that post only. But here all the images combined for all posts of a particular user are being displayed each time in every post. How to resolve it?

Comment: You are querying all posts in a view, you need a route and view which accept a particular id to show the post and its related images only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put yourself in that dilemma, you can fix the view code to fix that easily

```
def show_posts(request):
    posts = PostModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    
    for post in posts:
        post.images = ImagesPostModel.objects.filter(post=post))

     context = {
         'posts': posts,
     }

   return render(request, 'show_posts.html', context)
```

and then you iterate over post.images in the template

OR you use `post.images_set.all()` to access the post images.

Comment: It worked, but can you help me to understand that post is an object of PostModel, so how we can access images through it where images is a field of ImagesPostModel?

Comment: I don’t get the question

Comment: I am talking about posts = PostModel.objects.filter() will return an PostModel object. But PostModel doesn't have an images field in it. So how we are able to access images field of ImagesPostModel through PostModel object like post.images?

Comment: because we added the attribute 'images' to the post object, this is a trick in Python that you can manage the object's attributes after creating the object.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `related_name` for the `post` in your `ImagePostModel`. In your models.py you can do this.

```
class ImagesPostModel(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(PostModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="imagePost")
    images = models.ImageField()
```

And then in your template use `{{ post.imagePost.all }}`

Comment: It worked, but can you help me to understand that post is an object of PostModel, so how we can access images through it where images is a field of ImagesPostModel?

Comment: I think @Willem answered your question. Please accept answers that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can prefetch the images in bulk with:

```
def show_posts(request):
    posts = PostModel.objects.filter(
        user=request.user
    ).prefetch_related('imagespostmodel_set')
    context = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'show_posts.html', context)
```

then in the template, you can access the `.imagespostmodel_set` of the `post`:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    …
    {% for image in post.imagespostmodel_set.all %}
        {{image.post_id}}
        <img src="{{image.images.url}}" alt="postimage" style="width: 300px;">
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Model` suffix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`PostModel`</s> to `Post`.

Comment: It worked, but can you help me to understand that post is an object of PostModel, so how we can access images through it where images is a field of ImagesPostModel?

Comment: @Vansh_Chaudhary: if you define a `ForeignKey` on `ModelA` to `ModelB`, Django adds a way to access the `ModelA`s that refer to that `ModelB` with `mymodelb.modela_set.all()`.

Comment: Is it only for foreign Key or it is also in case of OneToOne, ManyToMany ?

Comment: @Vansh_Chaudhary: for all relations, so `OneToOneField`, and `ManyToManyField`s as well. You can change the name by specifying a `related_name="..."`.